# if message.attachments.size > 0 send that attachment to another channel discord.js

Tags: image, discord, discord.js

So whenever one person send an image or a message i need to send the same image or message to another channel, i tried with: `message.channel.send(message.content)` but that only works for messages, can you explain me how to do the same thing with images? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off, you would want to get the attachment sent in the message, and then of course check if there even was an attachment! This can be done using the `.attachments` extension of the `message` class:

```
const attachment = message.attachments.first(); // Would get the first attachment found in the message
if (!attachment) return; // Would do nothing if there was no attachment in the message.
```

After that was done with, we can simply get a channel object using it's ID or name, and then send the attachment over to it by typing:

```
const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get('id here'); // Gets the channel object
channel.send('some text here, can be left blank', attachment); // Sends the attachment with text (Will only send the attachment if left blank)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but instead of the image there is this writing: [ object Object ]

Comment: ``client.on('message', message => {
if (message.channel.id === 'id') { 
const attachment = message.attachments.first(); 
if (!attachment) return;
let channel = client.channels.cache.get('id');
channel.send(message.author.username + ': ' + message.content + attachment);
      }})``

Comment: Let me clean it up for you:
`channel.send(\`${message.author.username}: ${message.content}\`, attachment)`